# Executing JavaScript on a page with urllib

Tags: python, web-scraping, automation, python-webbrowser

I'm trying to create an automation for a site I need to access daily.
**I can't install any python libraries at the moment**.

I need to set a value into an input. And click on a button on this page.

I already managed to get the page content with urllib. But I can't figure out how to control the page.
It feels like if I could execute JavaScript code on the page my problem will be solved.
Is there a way to execute JavaScript with urllib?
Or any other way to automate a site without external libraries?

Comment: `urllib` is an Http Client and can't do things like clicking on buttons or setting values. That is the job of libraries such as Selenium. If, upon the button click, a post request is sent somewhere with the input value as the body, you can use urllib to send a POST request. However, this may not work since the backend would not allow such requests.

Comment: Yeah but I assumed those libraries do it using JavaScript and I want to do it manually.

Comment: urllib3 and all other similar packages are built entirely with Python and have nothing to do with JavaScript